# WinForms change Control/Panel/PictureBox contrast/brightness

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

how can I change Control/Panel/PictureBox contrast/brightness in WinForms, 
maybe something like SetColorAdjustment

Comment: You need to set the contrast/brightness of a backcolor or the entire form?

Comment: In my case, only for PictureBox, entire control

Comment: Quote: "Without affect the image".  You picked an appropriate user name.  Code that changes the contrast or brightness of an image is widely available.

Comment: In my case, I just can't change anything in image, I now how to change c/b, but I can't. Is a condition!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://www.authorcode.com/making-image-editing-tool-in-c-brightness-of-an-image/

(You also can download the source code)

Hope this can help you out..

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to change PictureBox.Image contrast/level, just only for PictureBox )

Comment: Sorry but I don´t understand then, what does the picture contains?

Comment: PictureBox, contains Image. But I don't need to change image contrast/brightness, image "bytes" must be unchanged.

Comment: Ok, then you need to achieve the same effect as the link I sent you but without changing the image?

Comment: Without affect the image )

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know then, maybe you can try using two images, a darken one and a brighten one. And then change the opacity in runtime. But I´m not sure, sorry for not being too helpful. Good luck!